# webpack to bundle existing css

Tags: webpack

I need to bundle existing css files with webpack 2. These were previously bundles with ASP.NET MVC. When I read the literature regarding web pack support I see that you need to use css loader with extract text plugin and you need to require the css from Javascript.

What I want to do is just define a bunch of CSS files to bundle together and minify without starting from Javascript files.

How can I do this? Do I need to use a special loader for it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just import your styles from your `index.js`?

Alternatively, you could setup a task runner like **gulp** to watch your styles folder although this seems redundant given that webpack can already handle this for you.

Paired with the extract text plugin, you'll have the same end result anyways.

Answer (score 0):

What i finally did was to make one js file per bundle I want to have.

For example

- /src/content/legacy.css.js
- /src/content/main.css.js
- ... (other legacy bundles I need to keep supporting)

Each [name].css.js file only contains some import statements:
e.g.

```
import "~/content/compact.css";
import "~/content/responsive.css";
// for the ~ character I used an alias in webpack
```

Then in the webpack.config file I point to those css.js files.
I then use css-loader, style-loader and extract-text-plugin to create a separate css file outputted in the dist folder.

With a custom npm package.json script I clean up the generated js files.

This way I get css bundles which I can expose again.

Note that my particular project contains css distributed over multiple applications so it's not an internal application css.

I just followed following article:
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/